# How to fix errors importing modules on python3

Tags: python-3.x, python-module

I successfully import modules on python but I keep having the same output error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named ''` error.

I installed matplotlib, eyeD3 and mutagen several times within the mac terminal:

```
#I used this code to install matplotlib on mac terminal
pip install --user  matplotlib

#I used this code to install eyeD3 on mac terminal
pip install eyeD3
```

As I try to import matplotlib like the code below (or eyeD3) I get that Traceback error.

```
#to import matplotlib for example
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
x = [1,2,3]
y = [2,4,1] 
plt.plot(x, y) 
plt.xlabel('x - axis') 
plt.ylabel('y - axis') 
plt.title('My first graph!') 

plt.show()
```

All of the modules listed above installed correctly, but when I import one of the modules I get the same common error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named ''`

Comment: are you using `pip install` from within the code?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that I'm using pip instal from within the terminal on a mac. "import matplotlib..." is the code that I am trying to execute on sublimetext that results in Traceback as no module has been installed apparently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have at least 2 version of python on your computer.
When you write `pip install matplotlib`, it install matplotlib on python.
But when you start the programm, an other version of python is launch.

To fix it : 
The command `python -m pip install matplotlib` will install matplotlib on the version that you want. 
If you want to use python 3.X, just write `python3 -m pip install matplotlib`
If you want to use the last version that is install on your computer, write `py -m pip install matplotlib`.
You can do that for every module that you have to install.

I hope it will help you.

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked just perfect. I just installed all of the modules and they run fine now. Thanks again!